# SQL query to compare date columns with int column with difference of 180 days or more

Tags: sql

In a table named table there are two columns opendate(datatype-datetime) and Xdate(datatype-int). In result I need value in which the difference between opendate and Xdate should be greater than or equal to 180days.

Table:

| Name | opendate | Xdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 20210815 |
| BBB | 2022-01-02 00:00:00 | 20211215 |

Expected result :

| Name | opendate | Xdate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 2022-01-01 00:00:00 | 20210815 |

Since there is more than 180 days gap difference between Xdate and opendate
also I am using sql server mangement studio.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Remove excess tags.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the integer to a CHAR before you can convert to date. [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, CONVERT (DATE, CONVERT(CHAR(8), Xdate)), opendate) >= 180;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below SQL script, replace the placeholder 'table' with your table name (without quotes), and syntax is for SQL Server:

SELECT * from 'table'
Where DATEDIFF (d,  CONVERT (datetime,convert(char(8),xdate)),opendate) >= 180